# Github workflows not triggered by automatically created PRs

Tags: github-actions, pull-request

I implemented a workflow that runs once a week and updates all the project dependencies and opens a PR with its changes using the workflow token.

```yaml
name: Automatic dependency update
"on":
  workflow_dispatch: null
  schedule:
  - cron: 0 0 * * 1
jobs:
  update:
    name: Update to latest versions
    runs-on:
    - self-hosted
    - default-runner
    steps:
    - name: Checkout Project
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Install Java
      uses: actions/setup-java@v2
    - name: Update Versions
      run: |
        ./gradlew useLatestVersions --info 
    - name: Commit and open PR
      uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v3
      with:
        commit-message: Update to latest versions
        committer: Update Bot <workflow@xxx.com>
        branch: auto-dependency-update
        base: dev
        delete-branch: true
        title: Automatic dependency update
        draft: false
        team-reviewers: XX/teamname
        body: Automated gradle dependency updates
```

The issue is, that for this PR the normal workflows (that are mandatory for the PR merge are not triggered.

```yaml
name: Build pipeline
"on":
  workflow_dispatch: null
  pull_request:
    branches:
    - dev
  push:
    branches:
    - '!master'
    - '**'
defaults:
  run:
    shell: bash
jobs:
  build:
    name: Compile
    runs-on:
    - self-hosted
    - default-runner
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: actions/setup-java@v2
    - name: Compile code
      run: |
        ./gradlew classes testClasses --info   
# ...
```

When I manually push something to that branch, the workflows are triggered. Though when I add the following step to the version update workflow, then the workflows aren't triggered either.

So what can I do? I dont want to trigger the workflows explicityl (e.g. using `benc-uk/workflow-dispatch@v1`) to keep the update mechanism as generic as possible.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#triggering-a-workflow-from-a-workflow)

> When you use the repository's `GITHUB_TOKEN` to perform tasks, events triggered by the `GITHUB_TOKEN` **will not create a new workflow run**.

> This prevents you from accidentally creating recursive workflow runs. For example, if a workflow run pushes code using the repository's `GITHUB_TOKEN`, a new workflow will not run even when the repository contains a workflow configured to run when push events occur.

> For more information, see "[Authenticating with the GITHUB_TOKEN](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication)."

The action you're using to open the PR also states in the [Inputs section](https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request#action-inputs) that you can change the `GITHUB_TOKEN` scope as well, or use a **PAT**:

> GITHUB_TOKEN (permissions `contents: write` and `pull-requests: write`) or a repo scoped [Personal Access Token (PAT)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).

#### Solution

Therefore, you just need to add a `token` input to the `peter-evans/create-pull-request` action using a secret allowing you to trigger a workflow from another workflow.